# How to root Nexus 5

Tags: rooting, backup, nexus-5

How to root the [Nexus 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_5)?

What precautions to take? I have never tried it before.
Also suggest me what type of back up I should perform before rooting.

Comment: Just follow the instructions here : [Rooting Nexus 5](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5#root)
Next time do search on xda for any custom rom, rooting related information!

Comment: I recommend you take a look into our fine [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info). Once read, start following some of its links. You will find someone [already asked your question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/57490/16575).

Comment: @AadiDroid: Broken link. How about providing an answer summarizing the forum thread you wanted to link to, or better, based on more recent information?

Comment: @Izzy: That question *looks like* it asks how to root, but it actually asks for the behind-the-scene concepts (what normal rooters don't see nor need). As such, the answer is not a tutorial but a list of facts.

Comment: @AadiDroid Seems your link got broken. Just goes to a general N5 list, no rooting instructions on that page. See what I've meant back then when telling you to include the essentials? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Easy Way to Root Nexus 5
If you want to get root access on your Nexus 5 with simple steps, refer to the one click solution - iRoot. It offers two versions for rooting, which means you can root your Nexus 5 without PC as well. Before using iRoot to root your phone, unlock the bootloader on Nexus 5 at first.

Remember that unlocking the bootloader will factory reset your Nexus 5. So please back up your data in your Nexus 5 before doing this.

After unlocking the bootloader on your device, move to the steps on how to root Nexus 5. Here we take the iRoot PC version for example:
Step 1. Make sure your phone has USB Debugging Mode enabled in Developer Options. If not, please go to Settings -> About Phone and tap Build Number until the notification that Developer Options have been enabled pops up. Then back out a step and you can see it at the bottom of your Settings menu.

Step 2. Make sure you have installed Nexus 5 USB Drivers on your PC.

Step 3. Ensure your Nexus 5 battery is charged to at least 85%.

Step 4. [Download iRoot PC version](http://www.iroot.com/download/iroot) on your computer. Connect your Nexus 5 to your PC.

Step 5. iRoot wll detect your device automatically. After detecting, click “Root”.

Step 6. Now your Nexus 5 should be rooted already.

Note: You can also root Nexus 5 without computer with [iRoot apk](http://www.androidpureapk.com/2016/02/iroot-apk.html). Just download the apk version directly on your Nexus 5. Or download on your PC, and drag it into your Nexus 5.