# Nexus 5 stuck at Google screen after failed(?) rooting

Tags: rooting, nexus-5

Our [How to root Nexus 5](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63984/how-to-root-nexus-5) question has no answer, so I followed [the most OK-looking Nexus 5 rooting tutorial on the rest of the web](http://www.androidbeat.com/2013/11/root-nexus-5/), all went well until the step that says:

> After booting into recovery mode, tap the ‘Install’ button and then select the SuperSU ZIP file you had transferred

[image: Team Win Recovery Project ZIP file is corrupt]

The trap is that on that tutorial, what seems to be a link to the ZIP file is actually a link to a page containing the real link surrounded by advertisement. So when I pressed "Save Link As" I actually downloaded some HTML rather than the real ZIP.

Realizing that, I wanted to reboot to try again with the real ZIP so I pressed "Reboot", it proposed me to install SuperSU so I accepted, happy to get it done quickly. The phone seemed to install something, then started to reboot.

PROBLEM: The following animation has been looping for an hour already and no sign that it will ever end:

[image: Android loading]

QUESTION: How to correctly finish the rooting?
I am afraid that shutting it down now will brick the phone or something.

Comment: Shut it down, wipe the cache partition, and try booting it up. Nothing will happen.

Comment: @rjt.rockx: I shut down, started TWRP recovery, wiped to factory settings then wiped the cache, then launch system boot. After 5 minutes it is still on the same animation.

Comment: If all else fails, flashing a [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) from fastboot will generally solve boot issues. NB: If you do want to re-attempt rooting, that version of SuperSU is super old - it probably won't work. The latest (stable) version looks to be [2.65](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1538053).

Comment: CF Auto-root (https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/) would be a good option to root again after booting up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem:

- Download the latest stable SuperSU, it is the ZIP file that can be downloaded at http://download.chainfire.eu/supersu-stable
- Restart in TWRP Recovery mode
- Press Mount
- Delete the faulty ZIP and copy the right one instead (at the root of the filesystem)
- Fixed! Now continue with the tutorial normally.

*Thanks rjt.rockx and eldarerathis for the tips!*