# Rooting catch 22

Tags: rooting, nexus-5, factory-reset

I have a Nexus 5 phone purchased from Google, running Marshmallow (MMB29S).

Recently it started misbehaving.  When I try to open the "Data Usage" settings, they hang.  So I asked on some forums and was advised to do a factory reset.

I voiced concern that a factory reset will wipe all my settings and app settings, and it will take me hours (if not days) to get everything to work like I want to.

No problem, I was told, there's this magical app, Titanium Backup, that will back up everything for me and restore it afterwards.  Provided I have root.

So I looked around for rooting information, and [got the impression that I need to unlock the bootloader first](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/2x7jms/root_without_unlockingwiping/), which will wipe everything.

Catch 22.

Is there a better way?
Am I missing something?

Comment: Partly – depending for which part of your question ;) First, you'd like to take a look at our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) (I agree TiBu is the best, but having no root you might need to go for alternatives first). Second, is the requirement of an unlocked bootloader in order to root something specific to your device? That's unusual for rooting (but usual for installing a custom recovery or custom ROM).

Comment: You can opt for a one-click root method (I don't find them safe though and among them Kingoroot is horrible, given the type of questions we receive in its aftermath). The benefit it gives is that you don't have to unlock bootloader.

Comment: @Izzy, thanks for the link, but the article is a bit old, talking about Android 4 when the current is 6.0.1

Comment: @AlexO which article? I've linked to our backup *wiki.* Tag-Wikis here hold some generic info, basic background, first aid, and possible links to core questions. For the "latest trend" you then can switch over to the questions using the tag and order them by "newest". Fact is: rooting rarely requires bootloader-unlocking (except when achieved via flashing a custom recovery – the corresponding [how to root Nexus 5 question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/57490/16575) using *that* approach indeed is a bit older, which is why I didn't explicitly mention it ;) // And where's Android 4 there?