# Restoring deleted video on Android Marshmellow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted a video on my Nexus 5 running Android (6.0.1) Marshmellow. The device uses internal storage only. I'd like to recover the video and from what I already know from the Internet, there are desktop/mobile apps that can recover the file.

The problem is, all of the apps I've tried need **root access** to the system. Rooting the phone, on the other hand, <s>will</s> can **wipe all my data** (see the comments below), as far as I understood the process correctly. So, ironically, if I root, there will be no file to be restored.

**1. Is there any way to recover the lost file without the root access?**

or

**2. Can I root the phone without deleting all its data?**

Comment: Where did you read that *rooting* wipes a device? That's usually not the case. Also, have you already consulted our [data-recovery tag-wiki](/tags/data-recovery/info)?

Comment: I put it poorly into words, sorry. I read that rooting on some devices requires doing the *OEM unlock* or *bootloader unlocking* - which wipes all data. I tried 2 apps to root the phone but they failed for the reason unknown, so my guess is the unlock is needed in the case of my device. I will check the wiki.

Comment: Ah, in that case you're correct: Unlocking usually wipes the device. Though a Nexus 5 shouldn't be too difficult to root IIRC. Our [rooting index](/q/1184/16575) points to [Can I root my Nexus 5 without a custom image?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/57490/16575) You might wish to check that as well.